# TSQL - INSERT ENTRY if particular entry does not exist within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert an entry if there is no record indicating that the user from a group had logged out.

```
declare @test table (grp varchar(2),logged varchar(4),time datetime)

insert into @test (grp,logged,time)
values ('A1', 'IN','20181111 09:00:00')
      ,('A1', 'OUT','20181111 10:00:00')
      ,('A2', 'IN','20181111 09:10:00')
      ,('A2', 'IN','20181111 09:20:00')
      ,('A3', 'IN','20181111 09:30:00') 
      ,('A3', 'OUT','20181111 10:30:00')
```

Desired Output

```
+-----+--------+-------------------------+
| grp | logged |          time           |
+-----+--------+-------------------------+
| A1  | IN     | 2018-11-11 09:00:00.000 |
| A1  | OUT    | 2018-11-11 10:00:00.000 |
| A2  | IN     | 2018-11-11 09:10:00.000 |
| A2  | IN     | 2018-11-11 09:20:00.000 |
| A2  | OUT    | NULL                    |
| A2  | OUT    | NULL                    |
| A3  | IN     | 2018-11-11 09:30:00.000 |
| A3  | OUT    | 2018-11-11 10:30:00.000 |
| A4  | IN     | 2018-11-11 09:40:00.000 |
| A4  | OUT    | NULL                    |
+-----+--------+-------------------------+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your table?

Comment: So you want to insert an (grp, OUT, NULL) for all grp-s having the last time entry IN?  Sounds not so complicated, what have you tried?

Comment: @ ZorgoZ I have tried using order by partition to find out the counts of the logged data but I have no idea on how to proceed from there.

Comment: Where does A4 group come from? Also, are you really inserting into a table variable, or into an actual table? (for the last one you might be able to use triggers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 2 versions for you

```
CREATE TABLE SignIn(grp varchar(10), logged varchar(3), [time] datetime)
INSERT INTO SignIn
VALUES
('A1','IN'  ,   '2018-11-11 09:00:00.000'   ),
('A1','OUT',    '2018-11-11 10:00:00.000'   ),
('A2','IN'  ,   '2018-11-11 09:10:00.000'   ),
('A2','IN' ,    '2018-11-11 09:20:00.000'   ),
('A3','IN'  ,   '2018-11-11 09:30:00.000'   ),
('A3','OUT',    '2018-11-11 10:30:00.000'   ),
('A4','IN',     '2018-11-11 09:40:00.000'   )
```

THIS version is like you expected. For each in record you will get an OUT copy

```
INSERT INTO SignIn (grp, logged, time)
SELECT s.grp, 'OUT', NULL
FROM SignIn s
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT grp
        FROM SignIn
        GROUP BY grp
        HAVING  MAX(CASE WHEN Logged = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
        ) notSignedOut ON s.grp = notSignedOut.grp
```

But in case you don't want duplicated records and want only one out record for the group you can use option below:

```
    INSERT INTO SignIn (grp, logged, time)
    SELECT grp, 'OUT', NULL
        --ISLoggedOut = MAX(CASE WHEN Logged = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM SignIn
    GROUP BY grp
    HAVING  MAX(CASE WHEN Logged = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

the main logic is hidden under ISLoggedOut = MAX(CASE WHEN Logged = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END). For each group of records I added indicator if there is out record. and in case no - value will be 0.

another option is to use not exists clause

```
   INSERT INTO SignIn (grp, logged, time)
   SELECT s.grp, 'OUT', NULL
   FROM SignIn s
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM SignIn i WHERE i.grp = s.grp AND Logged = 'OUT')
```

personally I prefer to use HAVING, based on some experience it is sometimes faster that exists for big tables. 
e.g. for our example statement with having produces the next statistics

> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table 'SignIn'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

and exists statement:

> Table 'SignIn'. Scan count 2, logical reads 8, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.

looks like HAVING statement does less reads than EXISTS

Comment: There could be a slightly more comprehensive alternative by using this clause: `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Logged = 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) >= 1` which actually gives you the number of entities currently not logged out.

Comment: do you mean not exist?